# Lazy loading with formula doesn't working

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm looking for retrieve a calculated field from an entity.

I have a *Customer* entity and I want to know the total orders ordered by the customer but I need a lazy loading fetch, so I expect that "totalOrders" field will be calculated when *Customer.getTotalOrders()* it's called.

With the follow configuration the lazy loading doesn't work and *totalOrders* always is being calculated.
**What I'm doing wrong?**

XML Mapping on Customer entity:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.tumrapp.entities.Customer" table="customers">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="id" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>

        <property name="name" type="string">
            <column name="name" not-null="true" />
        </property>

        <property update="false" insert="false" name="totalOrders" type="int" lazy="true"
            formula="(select count(o.id) from orders o where o.customer_id = id)">
        </property>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Customer entity class:

```
public class Customer implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Integer totalOrders;

    //constructors
    //simple getters and setters
}
```

Query displayed on Hibernate console:

```
select
    customer0_.id as id61_0_,
    customer0_.name as name61_0_,
    (select
        count(o.id) 
    from
        orders o 
    where
        o.customer_id = customero0_.id) as formula1_0_ 
from
    customer customer0_ 
where
    customer0_.id=?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formulas will always be evaluated on the initial `select` and the lazy property will be silently ignored unless you add bytecode instrumentation (example via [Ant](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-lazyproperties) / [Maven](http://tricksdev.blogspot.ru/2009/03/hibernate-bytecode-instrumentation.html)) for the entity class. The same holds true for one-to-one joins.